# How to make a Button program? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, button

I have a question about making a button program. So, I made a few simple programs like "Guessing Game", "Snake Game", "Tetris", etc. and a button program. I would like to make a program that when you click the button, it runs the specific program. For example, if you click 'Button 1', it runs "Tetris." Any help would be awesome!

Here is the "Tetris" program (code).

```
package tetris;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tetris extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8715353373678321308L;

    private final Point[][][] Tetraminos = {
            // I-Piece
            {
                {new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1), new Point(3, 1)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2), new Point(1, 3)},
                {new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1), new Point(3, 1)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2), new Point(1, 3)}
            },

            // J-Piece
            {
                {new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1), new Point(2, 0)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2), new Point(2, 2)},
                {new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1), new Point(0, 2)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2), new Point(0, 0)}
            },

            // L-Piece
            {
                {new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1), new Point(2, 2)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2), new Point(0, 2)},
                {new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1), new Point(0, 0)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2), new Point(2, 0)}
            },

            // O-Piece
            {
                {new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1)},
                {new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1)},
                {new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1)},
                {new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1)}
            },

            // S-Piece
            {
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(2, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1)},
                {new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(2, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1)},
                {new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2)}
            },

            // T-Piece
            {
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2)},
                {new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1), new Point(1, 2)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1), new Point(1, 2)}
            },

            // Z-Piece
            {
                {new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(0, 2)},
                {new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 0), new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 1)},
                {new Point(1, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(0, 2)}
            }
    };

    private final Color[] tetraminoColors = {
        Color.cyan, Color.blue, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.pink, Color.red
    };

    private Point pieceOrigin;
    private int currentPiece;
    private int rotation;
    private ArrayList<Integer> nextPieces = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private long score;
    private Color[][] well;

    // Creates a border around the well and initializes the dropping piece
    private void init()
    {
        well = new Color[12][24];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == 11 || j == 22)
                {
                    well[i][j] = Color.GRAY;
                }
                else
                {
                    well[i][j] = Color.BLACK;
                }
            }
        }
        newPiece();
    }

    // Put a new, random piece into the dropping position
    public void newPiece()
    {
        pieceOrigin = new Point(5, 2);
        rotation = 0;

        if (nextPieces.isEmpty())
        {
            Collections.addAll(nextPieces, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
            Collections.shuffle(nextPieces);
        }
        currentPiece = nextPieces.get(0);
        nextPieces.remove(0);
    }

    // Collision test for the dropping piece
    private boolean collidesAt (int x, int y, int rotation)
    {
        for (Point p : Tetraminos[currentPiece][rotation])
        {
            if (well[p.x + x][p.y + y] != Color.BLACK)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Rotate the piece clockwise or counterclockwise
    public void rotate (int i)
    {
        int newRotation = (rotation + i) % 4;

        if (newRotation < 0)
        {
            newRotation = 3;
        }
        if (!collidesAt(pieceOrigin.x, pieceOrigin.y, newRotation))
        {
            rotation = newRotation;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    // Move the piece left or right
    public void move (int i)
    {
        if (!collidesAt(pieceOrigin.x + i, pieceOrigin.y, rotation))
        {
            pieceOrigin.x += i; 
        }
        repaint();
    }

    // Drops the piece one line or fixes it to the well if it can't drop
    public void dropDown() {
        if (!collidesAt(pieceOrigin.x, pieceOrigin.y + 1, rotation)) {
            pieceOrigin.y += 1;
        } else {
            fixToWell();
        }   
        repaint();
    }

    // Make the dropping piece part of the well, so it is available for
    // collision detection.
    public void fixToWell()
    {
        for (Point p : Tetraminos[currentPiece][rotation])
        {
            well[pieceOrigin.x + p.x][pieceOrigin.y + p.y] = tetraminoColors[currentPiece];
        }
        clearRows();
        newPiece();
    }

    public void deleteRow (int row)
    {
        for (int j = row-1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                well[i][j+1] = well[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Clear completed rows from the field and award score according to
    // the number of simultaneously cleared rows.
    public void clearRows()
    {
        boolean gap;
        int numClears = 0;

        for (int j = 21; j > 0; j--)
        {
            gap = false;

            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                if (well[i][j] == Color.BLACK)
                {
                    gap = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!gap)
            {
                deleteRow(j);
                j += 1;
                numClears += 1;
            }
        }

        switch (numClears)
        {
            case 1: score += 100;
            break;
            case 2: score += 300;
            break;
            case 3: score += 500;
            break;
            case 4: score += 800;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Draw the falling piece
    private void drawPiece (Graphics g)
    {       
        g.setColor(tetraminoColors[currentPiece]);
        for (Point p : Tetraminos[currentPiece][rotation])
        {
            g.fillRect((p.x + pieceOrigin.x) * 26, (p.y + pieceOrigin.y) * 26, 25, 25);
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        // Paint the well
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 26 * 12, 26 * 23);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
            {
                g.setColor(well[i][j]);
                g.fillRect(26 * i, 26 * j, 25, 25);
            }
        }

        // Display the score
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("" + score, 19 * 12, 25);

        // Draw the currently falling piece
        drawPiece(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Tetris");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(12*26+10, 26*23+25);
        f.setVisible(true);

        final Tetris game = new Tetris();
        game.init();
        f.add(game);

        // Keyboard controls
        f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                switch (e.getKeyCode())
                {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP: game.rotate(-1);
                    break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: game.rotate(+1);
                    break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: game.move(-1);
                    break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: game.move(+1);
                    break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: game.dropDown();
                    game.score += 1;
                    break;
                } 
            }

            public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e)
            {
            }
        });

        // Make the falling piece drop every second
        new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        game.dropDown();
                    }
                    catch ( InterruptedException e )
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the "Guessing Game" program (code).

```
package guessinggame;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame
{
    private int upperBound;

    public GuessingGame(int stop)
    {
        upperBound = stop;
    }

    public void playGame()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = (int)(Math.random() * upperBound) + 1;
        int guesses = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 - " + upperBound + ": ");

        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            i = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (i > num)
            {
                System.out.print("Too high. Try another number. :: ");
            }
            if (i < num)
            {
                System.out.print("Too low. Try another number. :: ");
            }

            guesses++;
        }
        while (i != num);

        System.out.println("Correct!");

        double percentage;
        percentage = (double)(guesses) / upperBound;
        int percen = (int)(percentage * 100);
        System.out.println("It took " + guesses + " guesses to guess the number " + num + ".\n" +
                           "You guessed " + percen + "% of the possible values.");
    }
}






package guessinggame;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGameRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response;

        int top;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Guessing Game. Range of highest number? :: ");
            top = keyboard.nextInt();
            GuessingGame run = new GuessingGame(top);
            run.playGame();
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (y, n) :: ");
            response = keyboard.next();
        }
        while (response.equals("y"));
    }
}
```

Here is the button program (code).

```
package button;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Buttons extends Frame
{
    public Buttons()
    {
        super("");
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //this.add("North", new Label("North", Label.LEFT));

        Panel centerPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));
        centerPanel.add(new Button("Button 0"));
        centerPanel.add(new Button("Button 1"));
        centerPanel.add(new Button("Button 2"));
        centerPanel.add(new Button("Button 3"));

        this.add("Center", centerPanel);
        Panel southPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        //Label test = new Label("Test");
        //test.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        //southPanel.add(test);
        Panel panel = new Panel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        Label test1 = new Label("Test1");
        test1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        Label test2 = new Label("Test2");
        test2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel.add(test1);
        panel.add(test2);
        //southPanel.add("South", southPanel);
        this.add("South", southPanel);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
             {
                System.exit(0);
             }
        });

        this.setSize(400,  200);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Buttons();
    }
}
```

So I want the first program to run when the 'Button 0' is clicked and the second program to run when the 'Button 1' is clicked. By the way, i'm using Eclipse.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

As each game class is having its `own main method` you can simply can the respective main method of the game you want to start.

As `main method is static` no need for any initialization, simply -

```
GuessingGame.main();
```

or

```
Tetris.main();
```

Comment: So I just need to put    GeussingGame.main(); and Tetris.main();        in the button program. Also, I have to put all the codes for the 'GuessingGame' program and 'Tetris' program in the button program, right? Plus, I have to make new classes in the Eclipse for both 'GuessingGame' and 'Tetris', right? Thanks for answering.

Comment: So should I just put  GuessingGame.main(); and Tetris.main();   into the main method of button program? Using Eclipse, I made a project and made three packages (GuessingGame, Tetris, button program). Then, I made classes which are the ones I posted. So do I need just need to put those two arguments? I tried but it runs separately...